# Cannot write CSV file from python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm been trying to create a csv file from this code, but it fails every time, I have tried different ways to place it inside the code but nothing has work so far.

I'm new to python and to Stack overflow.

If somebody can explain what I'm doing wrong it will be helpful.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
from time import sleep
import os
import sys

from bleson import get_provider, Observer, UUID16


import csv

GOVEE_BT_mac_OUI_PREFIX = "A4:C1:38"

H5075_UPDATE_UUID16 = UUID16(0xEC88)

govee_devices = {}

# ###########################################################################
FORMAT_PRECISION = ".2f"

# Decode H5075 Temperature into degrees Fahrenheit
def decode_temp_in_f(encoded_data):
    return format((((encoded_data / 10000) * 1.8) + 32), FORMAT_PRECISION)


# Decode H5075 percent humidity
def decode_humidity(encoded_data):
    return format(((encoded_data % 1000) / 10), FORMAT_PRECISION)

#focus here 

with open('temp.csv','w',newline='') as record:
    record = csv.writer(record)
    record.writerow(['Device Name','Device Address','Temp','Humidity'])

    def print_values(mac):        
        govee_device = govee_devices[mac]
        print(govee_device['name'],govee_device['address'],govee_device['tempInF'],govee_device['humidity'],govee_device['battery'])
        record.writerow(govee_device['name'])




# On BLE advertisement callback
def on_advertisement(advertisement):
    

    if advertisement.address.address.startswith(GOVEE_BT_mac_OUI_PREFIX):
        mac = advertisement.address.address

        if mac not in govee_devices:
            govee_devices[mac] = {}
        if H5075_UPDATE_UUID16 in advertisement.uuid16s:
            # HACK:  Proper decoding is done in bleson > 0.10
            name = advertisement.name.split("'")[0]

            encoded_data = int(advertisement.mfg_data.hex()[6:12], 16)
            battery = int(advertisement.mfg_data.hex()[12:14], 16)
            govee_devices[mac]["address"] = mac
            govee_devices[mac]["name"] = name
            govee_devices[mac]["mfg_data"] = advertisement.mfg_data
            govee_devices[mac]["data"] = encoded_data
            govee_devices[mac]["tempInF"] = decode_temp_in_f(encoded_data)
            govee_devices[mac]["humidity"] = decode_humidity(encoded_data)
            govee_devices[mac]["battery"] = battery
            print_values(mac)
        if advertisement.rssi is not None and advertisement.rssi != 0:
            govee_devices[mac]["rssi"] = advertisement.rssi
            

        

# ###########################################################################


adapter = get_provider().get_adapter()

observer = Observer(adapter)
observer.on_advertising_data = on_advertisement

try:
    while True:
        observer.start()
        sleep(2)
        observer.stop()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    try:
        observer.stop()
        sys.exit(0)
    except SystemExit:
        observer.stop()
        os._exit(0)
```

Error that Im getting is:

```
File "/home/pi/GoveeWatcher-master/python/goveeWatcher.py", line 37, in print_values
    record.writerow(govee_device['name'])
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. The `with open` statement needs to cover the whole code where you want to write to the file. The function definition in there doesn't make sense. Also, next time please exactly specify the error and/or faulty behavior.

Comment: Python blocks are delimited by indentation (or whitespace) rather than being delimited by curly braces or “begin/end” keywords, This means the code you have posted will not run close to what you are looking for. The example you linked to looks like it will do most of what you have asked for.  Maybe modify `print_values` function to also write the values to a csv file. If that doesn't work then read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question. Including error messages is very useful.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I tried to adjust the code but still cannot get it to work, @ukBaz I tried to modify the print function but still not working. Edited the question with more information. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be tempted to put the CSV writing functionality inside of the print_values function so it opens the file, writes the data, and then closes the file on each value that is found by the observer.

For example:

```py
#focus here 
def print_values(mac):
    govee_device = govee_devices[mac]
    print(govee_device['name'], govee_device['tempInF'])
    with open('temp.csv','a',newline='') as record:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(record, fieldnames=govee_device.keys())
        writer.writerow(govee_device)
```